# How to print a pos receipt pdf in a thermal printer in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, pos

Iv created a POS app. When a transaction is done the receipt comes from the backend as a pdf and I want to allow it to print in a thermal printer. Most packages create the receipt than print, but I already have a pdf receipt and want to print that ,any help?

Comment: that depend on the communication mode of the device (network based, bluetooth based, etc.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is no simple way to send a pdf to a POS printer. You would need to render the PDF and rasterise it into a bitmap that you can send line by line. It will be much much much easier to get the transaction details and generate your own receipt by sending commands (many printer use ESC/POS commands) to the printer